# Removing Spaces from cells in Column B VBA Macro Button - Refuses to work (was working flawlessly before)

Tags: excel, vba

Having an extremely hard time figuring this out. I created a macro that removes any spaces from the cells in column B:

[image]

In the image above: Baja Turkey Avocado_6S_HeroRegular_Mobile would turn into BajaTurkeyAvocado_6S_HeroRegular_Mobile after clicking my VBA Macro button.

My code was working PERFECTLY for months, and now it suddenly decided to not work at all. Here is my code:

```
Sub RemoveSpacing()

    Set AssetToolSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AssetName Sheet")
    Dim startingLine As Double
    startingLine = 2
    
    With AssetToolSheet
        Do While .Cells(startingLine3, 2) <> ""
            .Cells(startingLine3, 2).Replace " ", ""
            startingLine = startingLine + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The above code loops until if finds the first empty cell. Aren't there in the processed sheet empty cells? Try testing it on a small sheet, having words separated by spaces **in all used range**. Does it work as it 'used to work'?

Comment: You set `startingLine = 2` but. the loop uses another variable `startingLine3` ?

Comment: Probably easier to just calculate the range then use the Replace method on it in one go.

Comment: Sorry @CDP1802 that was just a mistake on my end when posting the question here. It is all good in the actual macro that I wrote, so doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: I would select the column then do find:Replace... so quick...

Comment: How is the data entered into the cells ? Is it pasted from somewhere else ?

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help. Seems like it is working on another users PC, but not on mine. Super strange.

Comment: Does the other use process the same sheet?